# Solving $|y-\sqrt{2}| \leq (\sqrt{2} - 1) |x-\sqrt{2}|$

Tags: inequality, absolute-value

I am an undergraduate student and currently I am working on inequalities and the properties of absolute values.
I am trying to solve the following problem, but I do not know how to approach it:

Being $x >= 0$. Suppose that $y = \frac{x+2}{x+1}$.
Calculate $\frac{y-\sqrt{2}}{x-\sqrt{2}}$. Deduce the following inequality:

$$|y-\sqrt{2}| \leq (\sqrt{2} - 1) |x-\sqrt{2}|$$

Comment: Have you calculated $ \frac{ y - \sqrt{2} } { x - \sqrt{2}}$? If yes, what is it? If no, do it first.

Comment: With the intermediate step, the answer falls out almost immediately, so show your work and explain where you're stuck.

Comment: @CalvinLin I calculated $\frac{y-\sqrt{2}}{x-\sqrt{2}}$, and I got $0 = y \cdot \frac{1 - \sqrt{2}}{x - \sqrt{2}} = y \cdot \frac{1}{x-\sqrt{2}} - \frac{\sqrt{2}}{x-\sqrt{2}}$, but from there I don't know what to do or how to approach the deduction of the inequality.

Comment: What is the expression for $\frac{y-\sqrt{2}}{x-\sqrt{2}}$? Your comment gave an equation for $\frac{y}{x-\sqrt{2}}$, but it might be a typo.

Comment: So I substituted $y = \frac{x+2}{x+1}$ in $\frac{y-\sqrt{2}}{x-\sqrt{2}}$ and I got $0 = y \cdot \frac{1 - \sqrt{2}}{x - \sqrt{2}} = y \cdot \frac{1}{x-\sqrt{2}} - \frac{\sqrt{2}}{x-\sqrt{2}}$.

Comment: Where did you get the $ 0 = y \cdot \ldots$ from? You have an expression, not an equation.

Comment: In particular, your equation implies that if $ x \neq \sqrt{2}$, then $ y = 0 $. This is clearly not true.

Comment: @CalvinLin yes, you are right. I probably got entangled with my notes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Show that

$$\frac{y-\sqrt{2}}{x-\sqrt{2}} = - \frac{ \sqrt{2} - 1 } { x + 1 }. $$

(This is the numerical answer to the intermediate step. The proof is just by expanding the algebra and factoring.)

Hence, conclude that

$$ \left| \frac{y-\sqrt{2}}{x-\sqrt{2}} \right| = \frac{ \sqrt{2} - 1 } { x + 1 } \leq \sqrt{2} - 1 . $$

Comment: Could you please help me understand how the absolute value is being applied?

I re-worked my solution and finally got the same equation as yours, after factoring the binomial product $$\frac{y-\sqrt{2}}{x-\sqrt{2}} = \frac{ x + 2 - x\sqrt{2} - \sqrt{2} } { (x + 1) (x - \sqrt{2}) }. $$
Thank you for your help

Comment: A) If $ k < 0$ then $|k| = -k$. Apply this to $k = - \frac{ \sqrt{2} - 1 }{x+1}$. B) For $ x \geq 0$, $\frac{1}{x+1} \leq 1 $.

Comment: Very helpful, thank you for your help 

Comment: could you please recommend or suggest any good undergraduate text books for introduction to analysis? or any other books that you consider helpful? Thank you :)